# Shift in pixels between 2 tissues in MRI

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have the following question: given a known chemical shift $\delta$ between 2 tissue proton resonances and a MR image sequence with a total spin-echo sampling time of $t$ ms, what is the spatial shift in pixels in images acquired using a magnet with known magnetic field strength $B0$?

I think the first step is to work out the difference in frequency between the 2 tissue proton resonances will be given by $\Delta \omega = \gamma * B0 * \delta$ but I don't know how to relate this to the pixels or the total sampling time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sampling time will allow you to deduce the total bandwidth, if you know the resolution of the image you can then work out the bandwidth/per pixel and then calculating your shift ought to be trivial.